# Undesired drag and drop behaviour with JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to add drag-and-drop functionality to my application, whereby the originator of the drag event is a `JTable`.  I am currently using the built-in drag support `JTable` offers by calling [`setDragEnabled(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDragEnabled%28boolean%29).

The problem I'm facing is that in order to commence a drag operation, one has to first click on a row of the table, and then release the mouse; it is only the **second** mouse press (and all subsequent mouse presses) that generate drag events.  This occurs even if the `JTable` loses focus - i.e. Once the first left-click operation has been performed, drag-and-drop works perfectly **until I swap in a new `TableModel`**.  When new model has been installed one needs to perform a left-click on the table before drags start working again.

Reading the API documentation for `setDragEnabled(boolean)` the implication is that this is the L&F's responsibility and hence there may not be anything I can do to solve this.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  I am using the Alloy L&F but would be reluctant to change it.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a hacky solution, which was to add a `MouseListener` to the `JTable` and hook into the `TransferHandle`r's `exportAsDrag` method when the mouse is pressed:

```
    final JTable actionTbl = new JTable();
    actionTbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            // Need to explicitly start a drag operation when the mouse is pressed.
            // Otherwise drags are only started *after* the user has clicked once
            // on the JTable (this could be down to the L&F not doing the right thing).
            actionTbl.getTransferHandler().exportAsDrag(actionTbl, evt, TransferHandler.COPY);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the javadoc of the `setDragEnabled` method

> When automatic drag handling is enabled, most look and feels (including those that subclass BasicLookAndFeel) begin a drag and drop operation whenever the user presses the mouse button over an item (in single selection mode) or a selection (in other selection modes) and then moves the mouse a few pixels.

If I read this correctly, you should get the desired behavior when you use single selection mode.

If you need that behavior combined with multiple selection, you could opt to manually handle the incoming mouse events on the table, and on mouse_down adjust the selection and then delegating the mouse event to the `JTable`. So in pseudo-code:

```
protected void processEvent(AWTEvent e) {
  if ( isMouseDownEvent( e ) ){
     adjustSelection( e );
  }
  super.processEvent( e );
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this. It is solely based on what I read in the javadoc, and might have some unwanted side-effects as the `JTable` itself will still handle the event and react on it

Answer (score 0):

Adamski's solution works really well, but I had to change `TransferHandler.COPY` in the last line to `TransferHandler.MOVE` in order for it to work:

```
final JTable actionTbl = new JTable();
actionTbl.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
        actionTbl.getTransferHandler().exportAsDrag(actionTbl, evt, TransferHandler.MOVE);
    }
});
```